# How to read parameter values from a file in Python

Tags: python, file

I'm starting to learn Python and encountered a few issues while trying to read values from a file.

My parameter file is somewhat like this:

```
var1 11111111
path_value "some/space containing path/file.txt"
var3 something
#some other values
var4 some/value1
var5 some/value2
var6 some/value3
```

This is my code:

```
file=open('this_file.txt')
for line in file:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    if(fields[0] in "var1"):
        ## this will give me 11111111
        var_1_value=fields[1]
    if(fields[0] in "path_value"):
        ## this will give me only till "/some/space
        path_value_contains=fields[1]
```

How do I fetch the path properly? I'm not sure this is an efficient way of doing things. Can you please let me know any better ways to do this?

I'm not using any modules.

Comment: I strongly suggest you use the `configparser` stdlib module if you want to have user-editable text files like this. If you don't need it to be user-editable, consider `pickle` instead.

Comment: Checkout the example for inbuilt [ConfigParser](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples). This is much simpler than implementing it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, I strongly recommend you use a stdlib module that's good at this, but if you're intent on rolling your own, here's the problem:

```
if fields[0] in "path_value"
```

That's not testing if `fields[0]` is *equal* to `"path_value"`, it's testing if `fields[0]` is any one of `"p"`, `"a"`, `"t"`, `"h"`, `"_"`, etc.

Try instead:

```
if fields[0] == "path_value"
```

---

That said, it seems you're having a totally different problem and that one is merely related to a copy/paste error. You can try doing this if you're on Python3:

```
for line in file:
    param_name, *param_values = line.split()
    param_value = ' '.join(param_values)
    # then proceed as usual
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing a custom text format and trying to read it back in, you can put your parameters into a dictionary and let the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html) do the rest of the work.

You can use `pickle.dump(object, file)` to write a Python object to a file.

Subsequently, you can use `object = pickle.load(file)` to read a Python object from a file.

This script writes a dictionary of parameters to a file:

```
parameters = {
    'var1': 11111111,
    'path_value': 'some/space containing path/file.txt',
    'var3': 'something',
    'var4': 52
  }

import pickle

file_name = 'parameters.pickled'

with open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
  pickle.dump(parameters, out_file)
```

This script reads the dictionary of parameters from a file:

```
import pickle

file_name = 'parameters.pickled'

parameters = pickle.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))

var1 = parameters['var1']
path = parameters['path_value']

print('var1 =', var1)
print('path =', path)
```

Comment: If you don't need this to be human-readable, this is absolutely the best answer! You can even do ugly things like `vars().update(parameters)`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about `vars().update()`. That's another interesting thing I've learned today.

Comment: Yeah I strongly recommend against mucking with the `vars()` dict directly, but sometimes you need to use an ugly tool to do an ugly job! :)